Provisioning Profile Doesn't Include NSInputMonitoringUsageDescription Entitlement - macOS App Won't Build
I’m working on a macOS app and encountered a problem after connecting my project to a provisioning profile, either manually or automatically. The app used to build successfully, but now it fails with the following error:
'Provisioning profile "First Profile" doesn't include the NSInputMonitoringUsageDescription entitlement.'
My app requires the NSInputMonitoringUsageDescription key in the Info.plist to monitor keyboard and mouse events as part of its functionality. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Checked the Info.plist: Confirmed that NSInputMonitoringUsageDescription is present with an appropriate description.
Recreated the Provisioning Profile: Tried generating a new provisioning profile via the Apple Developer Portal with all necessary entitlements.
Verified Code Signing: Ensured that the profile and signing certificate match the app’s bundle identifier.
Cleaned and Rebuilt the Project: Deleted derived data and cleaned the build folder in Xcode.
I suspect the issue might be related to missing configuration in the provisioning profile for macOS-specific entitlements. Does anyone know how to resolve this or confirm if additional steps are required to support this entitlement?
